# Select Issue - angular2-mdl-ext [Angular 4.0]

Tags: angular, angular-mdl

I'm using: Angular 4.0 and for material: https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl

extension: http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl-ext/select

The issue is using the **Select Component**, it always stay open. Doesn't look like it's the proper behaviour.

Looks like this:

[image]

Here's the Demo App:

```
 package:
    "@angular-mdl/core": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular-mdl/popover": "^0.6.3",
    "@angular-mdl/select": "^0.10.4",
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ENjMu4?p=preview

am i doing something wrong or missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to import the *Select* component css.

In order to import the missing styles, you can add

`@import url('https://unpkg.com/@angular2-mdl-ext/select@0.10.3/select.css');`

in your main `style.css`file.

If you are using webpack & scss in your local machine, you can import them like this as well

```
@import '~@angular-mdl/select/select';
```

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/MdM5ZCJcVnY4dDTwUD4n?p=preview)